# Temp XML Schema Collection is automatically created

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, service-broker, xml-schema-collection

I recently enabled Service Broker on my server and created a XML Schema Collection to validate the message.

Now I'm receiving alerts from my audit alert as the following

[image: Audit Message]

Looking at the Audit log I can see this change was made with my user (sysadmin) on the tempdb database.

I need to worry about this? Why this is happening somethimes?

If I don't need to worry, can I turn off only this alert whitout loose the rest of alerts for changes?

As always ¡Thanks!

Comment: Voting to move this to DBA SE.

Comment: Sorry the ignorance... What is DBA SE? I suppose is a section, this is something I can do or should be done by an admin?